# Django page loading time too slow due to long TTFB time

Tags: django, performance, formset

One of the pages in my Django app is loading very slowly. It contains a formset table with 30 items. The TTFB fime (time to first byte) is 14 seconds. If I have more rows, for example 50 rows, the TTFB time is about 30 seconds. The performance test in Chrome developer tools shows a large part where my page is idle. What can I do to find out how to improve performance?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The python-idle tag is for the stdlib IDE, not  program idling ;-).

Comment: Thanks @TerryJanReedy. I have already found that if I don't pass the foreign keys for ProductCode and Use columns, it loads superfast